# Local Database VS 2010 Windows Phone

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7

How to create local database in Visual Studio 2010 for Windows Phone?

Comment: Question shows little or no effort to research before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tons of links online on how to do that.
Some of them are:

[Local Database Overview for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

[How to: Create a Basic Local Database Application for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202876%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

[Windows Phone Mango Local Database(SQL CE) tutorials on WindowsPhoneGeek](http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/Windows-Phone-Mango-Local-Database%28SQL-CE%29-Introduction)